# The "top x% overall" text needs more padding

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, activity-tab

In the activity tab (meta site only), the text under the reputation needs more upper padding, it looks very close to the reputation above it.

Here's an image:

[image]

Comment: **Best arrow**. Must upvote.

Comment: I think you meant `padding`.. I don't agree with that - but I do think it should be `horizontally aligned` with the first digit of the percentage and the background color should be changed to blend in.. ;)

Comment: @yivi **No obligatory hand-drawn red circle.** Must down-vote.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate [Alignment issue in all the per site meta - activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316475/312043). The alignment is in all the Stack Exchange meta sites.

Answer (score 44):

I believe there's intentionally no `padding-top` and this might be due to the different background-color applied to the relevant div on SO, since on SE the div blends in to the parent-div with the same background-color:

[image]

Changing the background-color of the relevant div on SO from `#eff0f1` to `background-color: #fafafb` results in the same look as presented on SE:

[image]

And then it looks fine again..

Comment: The arrows [keep getting crazier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325242/289905). Is this a new [meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478/289905)?

Comment: @Xufox the term "meme" is so overloaded nowadays, a single image is already a meme. This is just a proud continuation of meta tradition to hand draw stuff in screenshots.

Answer (score 6):

The different background color on the meta profile rep has been removed, resolving this issue.

Comment: I can't even begin to compete with this level of hand-drawn graphics, so I respectfully decline to participate.