# Help and Improvement review queue "header" not floating to the top of the page

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, help-improvement

All of the review queues that I have access to float the portion of the header that explains what the queue is for along with the buttons so it is always visible if one scrolls down the page.

The Help and Improvement queue does not do this. The area that I'm referring to is the box right below the Review | Help and Improvement in the image below.

[image: Non-floating header example]

This is a request to make it float when scrolling down like the rest of the review queue headers do.

Comment: Not sure what I should do here, there is no free hand circle, and it says `float` instead of `fixed`.. but the post has sense

Comment: My free hand red circle was broken when I posted.

Comment: Try *best arrow*, [like this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381230/the-top-x-overall-text-needs-more-padding)

Comment: Looking at [the code](https://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/Js/review.en.js), it seems that this feature has been deliberately disabled (search for `disableDockedReviewBar`) in that particular review queue. I'm not sure why, but perhaps it somehow conflicts with the inline edit box you get when clicking the "Edit" button. (Of course, if that's the reason, I wonder why it's not disabled only when the edit box is active. That doesn't seem like it should be particularly difficult to do.)

Comment: ...in fact, you can copy the code of the `dockReviewBar()` function from the `review.en.js` script I linked above and paste it into the JS console while in the Help and Improvement queue to see what would happen if the floating review bar wasn't disabled there. It's indeed slightly glitchy when the edit box is open, but not particularly badly so. And AFAICT it's nothing that a couple more lines of JS code (e.g. to temporarily make the bar static whenever the edit box is open) couldn't fix.